# Python ignoring lines while reading a file

Tags: python, file, file-handling

I am trying to print a .log file to the console. The function im using is:

```
def read():
    outputData = open('/Users/me/Desktop/folder/output_test.log', 'r')
    rawOutputData = outputData.read()
    print(rawOutputData)
    outputData.close()
```

I also tried using

```
import io
import os

def read():
    outputData = io.FileIO(os.path.join('/Users/me/Desktop/folder/output_test_txt.log'))
    rawOutputData = outputData.read()
    print(rawOutputData)
    outputData.close()
```

Both of these printed the file to the console, however, there are fractions in the log file that these functions seem to ignore and I can't figure out why. There are recurring parts of the log file that look as follows:

```
[...
[2018.10.30 13:22:31]- [AVL.WRITE]->Record Saved:
[2018.10.30 13:22:31]-[AVL] SOURCE: 0
HDOP Actual:    0.8

Timestamp:  1540905751000
Priority:   0
Longitude:  99635883
Latitude:   599993683
Altitude:   55
Angle:      179
Sat:        14
Speed:      0


Event IO ID:    0

IO[  1]: 1
IO[179]: 8
IO[ 66]: 26176
IO[ 21]: 5
IO[ 62]: 0x0000000000000000
IO[ 72]: 2
IO[236]: 11
IO[237]: 19
IO[238]: 5242

Record Size:    60 Bytes (25,35)
[2018.10.30 13:22:31]-[FLASH]-> New Rec Addr: 1E100 Len: 97
[...
```

If I execute the function this part of the log file gets printed as:

```
[...
[2018.10.30 13:22:31]- [AVL.WRITE]->Record Saved:
[2018.10.30 13:22:31]-[AVL] SOURCE: 0
HDOP Actual:    0.8
Speed:      0


Event IO ID:    0




Record Size:    60 Bytes (25,35)
[2018.10.30 13:22:31]-[FLASH]-> New Rec Addr: 1E100 Len: 97
[...
```

This also happens to several other parts of the log file that have about the same format, so im guessing it is due to that? I just need to know why this is happening.

FYI my goal at some point is to extract the data between

```
[XXXX.XX.XX XX:XX:XX]-[AVL] SOURCE: 0

... #this is the data of the log file I need

[XXXX.XX.XX XX:XX:XX]-[FLASH]-> New Rec Addr: 1E100 Len: 97
```

and put them in a different file to analyse them.

(Please keep in mind im still at a novice stage when it comes to Python and might be overlooking a very basic mistake)

EDIT01:
The idea @9769953 had seems to be correct. If I use:

```
 print(repr(rawOutputData))
```

the console prints out:

```
[AVL.WRITE]->Record Saved:\r\n\r\n[2018.10.30 13:22:31]-[AVL] SOURCE: 
0\r\n  HDOP Actual:\t0.8\r\r\n  Timestamp:\t1540905751000\r  
Priority:\t0\r  Longitude:\t99434683\r  Latitude:\t535483683\r  
Altitude:\t55\r  Angle:\t\t179\r  Sat:\t\t16\r  Speed:\t\t0\r\n\r\n 
\r\n Event IO ID:\t0\r\n\r\n \tIO[  1]: 0\r \tIO[179]: 0\r \tIO[ 66]: 
26146\r \tIO[ 21]: 5\r \tIO[ 62]: 0x0000000000000000\r \tIO[ 72]: 0\r 
\tIO[236]: 15\r \tIO[237]: 11\r \tIO[238]: 1022\r \n \n \r\n Record 
Size:\t60 Bytes (25,35)\r\n[2018.10.30 13:22:31]-[FLASH]-> New Rec 
Addr: 1E100 Len: 60\r\n [PERIODIC.GPS.INFO]:\r\n \n Module:\t\r GPS 
State:\t1 / gps on\r
```

So it actually contains all the data in the original log, however, it also contains other escaped letters than ('\n').
Any idea how to resolve the issue of these invisible control characters?

Comment: There may be invisible control characters in the log file that mess up printing it through Python. See what you get doing `print(repr(rawOutputData))`. It will be a bit messy perhaps, but if you see escaped characters other than a new line (`'\n'`), this could be the cause.

Comment: This is indeed strange behavior, and I am unable to reproduce it based on the information shown. Can you play around and get the *minimal* input file that shows the error, and post it here. Use the method suggested by @9769953

Comment: I think we need access to the file to know what is happening.  Perhaps the lines that seem to be missing in the printed output are terminated by just a `'\r'` character, so when you print the data with the `print()` function, the next line overwrites the previous line.  For example: `s = "Ellen Ripley\rDana Barrett\rGwen DeMarco\r"; print(s)`

Comment: Instead of `print(rawOutputData)`, try `lines = rawOutputData.splitlines()` followed by `for line in lines: print(line)`